# How To make Many Unique team From Given Players

Tags: php

i am trying to making team of 11 player for tournament like cricket and all that ,but team must be unique i mean no player comes twice in same team
For Example:-i have 22 players

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
or we have 22 players in two teams
first team:-1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11
second team:-12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22
```

now i need a team for unique players like this
1,2,5,19,18,22,8,6,15,13,17

i try below code

```
$candidates = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

var_dump(getTeam($candidates));

function getTeam($candidates, $team_size = 3)
{
    shuffle($candidates);
    return array_chunk($candidates, $team_size);
}
```

but this will give me output for 12 candidates and it will make team form 12 condidtes
is there any  way to make team from 22 players also team must be in simple string not in any var_dump or array sting

Comment: You only will have two teams out of 22 players, correct? Is this *always* the case? ... Oh I see now, you want team size to be adjustable. Why not have candidates be all of the player id's then shuffle and split.

Comment: GetSet  sir can you please explain how to do it please help

Comment: @RobRuchte below is insightful on the hows CandyCrush. The last team will be of lesser players than the others in his solution (and in any solution) if total players is not evenly divisible by team size.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on the right track, your function makes random teams of the correct size from the candidates you pass in. You could leverage that to get single teams. As for what to do with the results, they are just [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php), so you can do anything you want with them - this joins them with commas using [`implode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and echos them out.

```
<?php
$candidates = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12);

function getTeams($candidates, $team_size = 3)
{
    shuffle($candidates);
    return array_chunk($candidates, $team_size);
}

function getRandomTeam($candidates, $team_size = 3)
{
    $teams = getTeams($candidates, $team_size);
    return array_shift($teams);
}

$output = getTeams($candidates);

echo 'Teams:'.PHP_EOL;
foreach($output as $currTeam)
{
    echo implode(', ', $currTeam).PHP_EOL;
}

$output = getRandomTeam($candidates);

echo 'Random Team: ';
echo implode(', ', $currTeam).PHP_EOL;
```